# Error while Updating the list item in Vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

> Hi All,
>
> I have created a simple `CRUD operation in VueJS.` The values are
>   inserting in a list , i can read it from there only and also can
>   delete it from the list. But issue is when i am trying to update any
>   value, its not getting update. Can any one help me out with it. Am i
>   doing anything wrong. Please let me know.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>    
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="addToDo">
            <input v-model="currentTodos" type=text><br><br>
            <button type="submit">Add To List</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
                {{todo}}<button v-on:click="deleteItemFromList(index)">X</button><button v-on:click="updateItemList(index)">#</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div v-html="htmlContent"></div>    
    </body>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app", // el is the DOM element.
            data:{
                 todos:['push', 'pop', 'paste'],
                 currentTodos: '',
                htmlcontent : "<div><input type="text"></div>"
            },
            methods:{
                addToDo: function(){
                 this.todos.push(this.currentTodos);
                 this.currentTodos = '';   
                },

                deleteItemFromList: function(index){
                    this.todos.splice(index,1)
                },

                updateItemList: function(index){
                    this.todos.set(index,1)
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think array did not have `set` method.

Comment: @bcjohn  can you help out with the set method, as i am a newbie in Vue,

Comment: `this.todos[index] = newVal`. Just change the value of array is fine.

Comment: what does this newVal do.

Comment: It is a new value that you want to replace the old ones.

Comment: I have added above line of code in my updateItemList function,now my question is how can get this newVal. in my HTML code, or update a specific value from the list. and thanx for the code. @bcjohn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192768/discussion-between-prathamesh-doke-and-bcjohn).

Answer (score 1):

`Reactivity` is not working here. Assign a new Array reference when changin `todos` array or you can use [this.$set(...)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) to get the reactivity working.

```js
methods:{
  addToDo: function(){
    this.todos.push(this.currentTodos);
    // assign a new Array reference in this.todos
    this.todos = [...this.todos];
    this.currentTodos = '';   
  },

  deleteItemFromList: function(index){
    this.todos.splice(index,1);
    this.todos = [...this.todos];
  },

  updateItemList: function(index){
    this.todos[index] = '1';
    this.todos = [...this.todos];
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
...
<li v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="todo">
    {{todo}}
    <button v-on:click="deleteItemFromList(index)">X</button>
    <button v-on:click="updateItemList(index)">#</button>
</li>
...
</template>
```

And also add `:key="todo"` in `v-for`

Comment: hi sir, i have tried your code and added "<li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
                    {{todo}}<button v-on:click="deleteItemFromList(index)">X</button v-on:click="updateItemList(index)"><button>Update</button>
                </li>" this in my html code but it is not working

Comment: i have added update button and passing the index of a select value

Comment: Try `this.todos[index] = 1;` & here the updated value = 1 (hard coded)

Comment: do you see any error in chrome console? anyway, `addToDo()` & `deleteItemFromList()` are working?

Comment: yes those methods are working but updateItemList() is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192778/discussion-between-prathamesh-doke-and-sajib-khan).